# How to rename an array/vector automatically in R?

Tags: r, arrays, vector

I wrote a (not pretty, but working) function to make one long vector from a certain column of my dataframe and add in a certain number of NA's every time the ID changes. Now what I am looking for is a possibility to automatically rename the variable array within the function so the output of the function carries an individual name (to make it easy to identify which values are in there and to prevent it from getting overwritten when running the function for a different column). One possibility would be to rename it with x or array_x. Now what I tried is several variations of this:

```
c("array_", as.character(x)) <- array
rm(array)
print(c("array_", as.character(x)))
```

But it only throws errors- I assume because the string is not recognized as a variable name. Can anyone help me on solving this?

Here is some example data and the part of the function that is already running:

```
ID <- c(rep ("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
Day <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
Score1 <- c(12,4, 16, 9, 12, 13)
Score2 <- c(1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 5)
Score3 <- c(23, 19, 12, 12, 24, 11)

df <- data.frame(ID, Day, Score1, Score2, Score3)
print(df)


foo <- function(x) {  

array <- c(df[1,x])

for (i in 2:nrow(df))
  
{
  if (df[i, 1] == df[i-1, 1 ]) {
    array <- append (array, df[i, x])
  }
  else 
  {
      array <- append (array, rep (NA, 5))
      array <- append (array, df[i, x])
  }
}
#rename array
print (array)
}

foo("Score1")
```

Comment: I don't understand what the desired output of your function is. Normally functions return values; they do not returned named variables. Names of variables are lost when the function returns

Comment: `array` is a bad choice for a name, it already is a base R function. If you want to give the output a name why not simply assign the function output to a variable with that name? `array_x <- foo("Score1")`.